# mongo and java finding nested keys and values

Tags: java, mongodb

my mongo collections contains following documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52d43cd29b85346a4aa6fe17"),
    "windowsServer" : [
    {
        "topProcess" : [ ]
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52d43cd29b85346a4aa6fe18"),
    "windowsServer" : [
    {
        "topProcess" : [ {pid:1,name:"wininit"}]
    }]
 }
```

Now in my java code I want to used only topProcess in above case I want only second document  which topProcess having some data. For this I write my java code as below

```
BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject projections = new BasicDBObject();
criteria.put("windowsServer.topProcess", new BasicDBObject("$ne", "[]"));
projections.put("windowsServer.topProcess",1);
DBCursor cur = coll.find(criteria,projections);
while(cur.hasNext() && !isStopped()) {
    String json = cur.next().toString(); 
}
```

when I execute above code and print json string it also contains the both topProcess. Can any one knows how should I get only second documents topProcess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (and translate it to your java driver):

```
"windowsServer.topProcess": {$not: {$size: 0} }
```

Comment: This is correct.  In Java, this translates to: `criteria.put("windowsServer.topProcess", new BasicDBObject("$not", new BasicDBObject("$size", 0)));`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you only have mistake in the following line.

```
criteria.put("windowsServer.topProcess", new BasicDBObject("$ne", "[]"));
```

You try to compare if an array is empty by using brackets as a String. You can use **BasicDBList()** for an empty array. Update above line with the following and it should work.

```
criteria.put("windowsServer.topProcess", new BasicDBObject("$ne", new BasicDBList()));
```